# Logcat shows random/irrelevant errors

Tags: android, logcat

It's so annoying when logcat shows errors which are not related to my app at all. I turned off my app in the emulator and still this error will print after every 15-20 seconds

```
06-08 18:22:50.685 2350-14664/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
                                                                                               com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
                                                                                                Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
                                                                                                   at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
```

It makes debugging a bit tedious and I really want to do something about it.

**EDIT**-Even after using the filter I get random `googlequicksearchbox` errors

```
06-08 18:20:34.728 2350-14241/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
06-08 18:20:34.732 2350-14241/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
06-08 18:20:34.732 2350-14241/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
06-08 18:20:34.732 2350-14241/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
06-08 18:20:39.760 1306-3296/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
06-08 18:20:39.762 1306-1691/? E/AudioFlinger: openRecord() permission denied: recording not allowed
```

PS: I am not using any voice related stuff in my app.

Comment: You can make a filter in the logcat panel of Android Studio to only show the log from your app

Comment: Why are you concerned about the speech recognizer? All devices output random errors. That's why there's a logcat filter

Comment: LOL I feel dumb, yeah it works fine now. But does this snippet mean something is wrong with my emulator?

Comment: Eh, so the problem isn't solved actually. Look at edit.

Comment: Unless it is causing you problems, you can ignore this error

Comment: But I don't understand what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Go To File menu on Android studio they have a option invalidate cache and restart and press this option .
when You invalidate cache and restart then . Approx Your Problem solved

Comment: Haha yeah it solved my problem, kinda weird because it is not making any sense to me. Why would emulator or logcat go crazy I have just been coding from a week or two.

Comment: I chose it as an answer, my reputation is low my upvote will not show :(

Comment: Thanks For Your Coperation

Answer (score 1):

You could use pidcat (https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat) - Pidcat is a colored logcat script which only shows log entries for a specific application package.